# Wordpress: Removing External Google map source

Tags: php, wordpress, function, api, hook

I am trying to remove the google maps api link attached to the wordpress backend. Tried following code but its not working

```
function dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places' );
   wp_dequeue_script( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&#038;libraries=places' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Also search internet so did not found any relivant solution to get ride of google map api.

Reason to do is i am getting following error in source when inspect element

```
You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

and in backend when try to edit the post, it is causing the extra loading time on page of almost 40s. So really need to get ride of google map api through out website, disabled all plugins it is coming from the theme called Motors.

ADDITIONAL:

I tried all following codes and added them to functions. I manage to remove 2 scripts mentioned above from loading in backend and get ride of error, however there are few more maps.googleapis.com links that are not being removed. Those appear once i tried edit post and visual composer loads, these are causing extra slow speed.

```
function de_script_maps_js1() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'common-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/44/13/intl/no_ALL/common.js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'common-js' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'de_script_maps_js1', 99999 );

function shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'control-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/44/13/intl/no_ALL/controls.js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'control-js' );
    
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area', 99999);

function shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area1() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'util-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/44/13/intl/no_ALL/util.js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'util-js' );
    
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area1', 99999);

function shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area2() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'places-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/44/13/intl/no_ALL/places_impl.js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'places-js' );
    
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_disable_scripts_styles_admin_area2', 99999);
```

Comment: visual composer is full of crap anyway ;-) but thats a different story. Is it embedded in the theme? Check the theme's file. Else if its in visual composer. You maye have entered a key for the google maps api. If so, go to the google api dashboard and just remove the link there. It will break the link, thus increasing speed.

Comment: no, there is no api key set but still resources loads from maps.googleapis and it takes page to load for almost 40 second before its fully loaded. And i tried all method, and above hooks took. Nothing helps.

Comment: hi there  - 

I am having a heck of a time disabling google maps from the jobify-theme. I have followed the instructions from the documentation page on adding: but the site still fetches the google-data: in other words, the site still pulls the data from google - see the results:
 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412666/remove-google-maps-completely-from-the-wordpress-site
 
look forward to hear from you